# The argument 2 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath

I've been a multilingual developer for over 30 years.  I am increasingly frustrated with tsql limitations due to its declarative nature.  Currently, I have a function that returns a datatype as a varchar(n) and am trying to pass this datatype as a string to the xml value method **2nd argument** as a parameter (note previous posts are for **1st argument** and I tried **sql:variable("@DatTyp")**).  I can think of no good reason why MS would implement the query method in this way.  Here's my test code stub:

```
    DECLARE @xmlHandle      int
    exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlHandle OUTPUT, @xmlTableSchema

    Set @DatTyp = [GlobalCnlyCentralizedMedicaids].[dbo].[fnGetDataTypeFromXML]('EmailTo', @xmlHandle)

    -- this line produces the error in the title of this question
    set @emailRec = @xmlTableData.value('(/TableData/TableRow/@EmailTo)[1]',@DatTyp)

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xmlHandle
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Much thanks in advance!

Comment: The first idea: Hands away from `OPENXML` and `sp_xml_preparedocument` / `sp_xml_removedocument`. This is outdated. Stay with the XML/XPath/XQuery methods like `.value()`, `.query()` and `.nodes()` The second thing is: Yes, the data type is a literal and there is now way round unless you go with dynamic SQL.

Comment: This might be an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe what you want to do and why you need this. There might be a completely different approach...

Comment: Antoher lesson learned.  Do not spend a half hour responding to a comment on this website without signing in first.  Whatever you typed in this box, get's lost after leaving the page to sign in prior to your post - brilliant!

Comment: **XY-Problem?**  While I suspect that the original problem can be solved in any manner of different ways, as we say in the USA, there are a "million ways to skin a cat," the original intent was to handle any small table in a completely agnostic way - meaning I wanted the calling program to avoid having any knowledge of the underlying settings table format.  I suspect that a better solution may be for me to research using a JSON implementation rather than MS's XML implementation within tsql.  Suffice to say, I believe that I once again have found myself trying to make tsql do what it cannot.

Comment: Mark, wouldn't you lose all advantages a RDBMS can bring to you by defining a *completely agnostic* data structure? Why should you use a RDBMS at all? There are common patterns like Key-Value-Pairs or EAV, but there are very good reasons not to use them...

Comment: Not really, I understand the K-V-P or EAV and agree that they (RDBMS's) bring structure, but as far as the processing logic is concerned, the strong typing that an RDBMS brings along with it can get in the way at times.  In my case, we are stuck with a ton of db instances across a number of servers with a dozen or more clients' data exists.

I think that there are a lot of companies out there that have their data locked up in an RDBMS (flavor independent) where they either rely on the application for relational integrity or the db design or sadly, said company just doesn't care.

Comment: Don't misunderstand, I use an RDBMS (this time its sql server) and I think it's great but I want the back-end application (where much of the business logic is) to gather its settings from any settings table regardless of its current structure.  They are all similar but as time marches on, they continue to develop toward a common more inclusive structure.  In essence, I want to supply my sproc or function with a table reference and pull out the desired field without having to specify the datatype that said sproc or function derives from the specified table reference - small tables only.

Comment: So, in conclusion, maybe not _completely agnostic_.

Comment: Sorry not enough rep to chat.  Gottfried, saw your CV, very impressive.  Can you tell me if SQL Server/tsql has anything to offer along the lines of a hybrid OO solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the XML isn't actually stored as XML but something easier to index. Try `EXEC` to get it to behave itself.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(8000) = '
DECLARE @xmlHandle      int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlHandle OUTPUT, @xmlTableSchema

Set @DatTyp = [GlobalCnlyCentralizedMedicaids].[dbo].[fnGetDataTypeFromXML]('EmailTo', @xmlHandle)

set @emailRec = @xmlTableData.value(''(/TableData/TableRow/@EmailTo)[1]'',' + @DatTyp + ')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @xmlHandle'
EXEC (@sql)
```